# Artemis JMS management API

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I am currently migrating Spring Boot 2.x application from ActiveMQ 5.x to Artemis, but I have an issue with Artemis `activemq.notifications` and `activemq.management`.

With ActiveMQ 5 I used `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection` topic to see if clients with specific clientId are currently connected. Connecting to this topic I received first all currently connected clients and after that being informed with `ConnectionInfo` and `RemovedInfo` if clients went offline or went online.

Unfortunately Artemis doesn't support this behavior. Listening to `activemq.notifications` only provides information about sessions created or sessions closed while listening at the topic.

So now I need to sync the connected clients on startup of my app.

I tried to access `ActiveMQServerControl.listConnectionIDs()` using JMS management API, but
`org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl.getAttribute()` method only allows access to methods starting with `get` or `is`.

Is there any other way to get the needed information (without polling)?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an operation instead of getting an attribute using something like

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.management.JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(m, ResourceNames.BROKER, "listConnectionIDs");
```

Please note this might not work, i just wanted to show you an example.